# Jest async/await breaks

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

**1. Jest Docs: An async example**
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async

**2. My test**

```js
describe('some test', () => {
  it('sets the correct instance properties ', async () => {
    const importService = new ImportService();
    const something = await importService.import();

    expect(something).toEqual(123);
    expect(importService.files).toEqual(files);
  });
});
```

3. Error:
   `Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function`
4. `.babelconfig` has `"@babel/preset-env",`

I have the async keyword, yet it still breaks.

Comment: `describe('some test', () => {` is not async.

Comment: There are some examples on the doc with `it` using `await`. I'm assuming those `it`s are within a `describe`

Comment: I'm not using async on describe, I'm using it on it

Comment: @GeorgeNorris (I'm assuming you're the OP using a different username). Async it must be inside an async describe. If you're not using describe, why put it in the question?

Comment: adding async to describe results in "Returning a Promise from "describe" is not supported. Tests must be defined synchronously.
        Returning a value from "describe" will fail the test in a future version of Jest.
"

Comment: No, the describe does not need `async`.  Your example is fine and works locally in my tests.  It must be something else - is the `import` function using `await` in its implementation?  If you could post the full error there might be some clue...

Answer (score 0):

You may be receiving this error because one of the functions you are testing is missing `async` where it is using `await`.

Try looking at the constructor of `ImportService` and the method `import()`.